# Can a ceramic power resistor catch fire?

Tags: power, resistors, safety, heat, ceramic

If I go over the max wattage of a ceramic power resistor by a few watts, can it catch fire/produce a flame?

Comment: Your question shows a lack of research. A search of the web for 'ceramic power resistor' would drown you in details, thus avoiding the need to annoy us with redundant questions.

Comment: @Sparky256 you are right, there are plenty of answers elsewhere. But none on Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Markusmoo It makes no sense to replicate the easiest to find information on EE.SE only to have it here. It doesn't make to rewrite every Wikipedia-Article in Q&A style to post it here, either. You could enhance the question by describing the use case. It might be something of interest for more than a few people.

Answer (score 1):

Vitreous enamel resistors are rated at 0W @ 350'C  (where you can bake cookies)

.. at 400'C they may burn cookies, melt solder and burn FR4 but not catch fire.

## Impressions

Judging by your lack of specs for temp rise and lack of details on overall thermal design, and lack of a datasheet or even evidence that you read one, I think either one of two conclusions will apply.  Murphy's law or eligible for Darwinian candidate.  *( if it doesn't say flame proof then it is flammable)*